# How get user data with Yii2 bearer authentication?

Tags: rest, api, yii2, bearer-token

I need to get the user data to use for the access control. I bearer authentication works fine, the user session is disabled.

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken ($token, $type = null) {       
    $user = static::findOne(['access_token' => $token, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    if ( $user ) {
        if ( $user->isAccessTokenValid() ) {
            $user->last_request = time();
            $user->save(false);
            return $user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `Yii::$app->user->id` and `Yii::$app->user->getId()` return `null` because the session is disabled.

I need to use it in:

```
$behaviors['access'] = ['class' => AccessControl::class,
    'only' => ['view'],
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['view'],
            'allow' => false,
            'roles' => User::isUserAdmin(Yii::$app->user->getId()),
        ],
        [
            'actions' => ['view'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => User::isUserManager(Yii::$app->user->getId()),
        ],
    ],
];
```

I tried to save the user data or the token in public static variable in the user class, but the variable always `null`.

Comment: although the session is disabled but the `Yii::$app->user->id` will be populated for the current request and **not across requests** can you confirm that your `findIdentityByAccessToken` method is not returning after `if ( $user->isAccessTokenValid() ) {` means does this statement returns true ? as it returns the `user` model object and if it does the `Yii::$app->user->id` should not be blank

Comment: also you need to specify the user `identityClass` in your `components` configuration, make sure it is correct

Comment: It also depends on what returns the method `getId()` implemented inside your User class. If the class extends ActiveRecord then it should return it from db. Usually you'll find the loaded user under `Yii::$app->user->identity` if identityClass is set up as suggested by @MuhammadOmerAslam. [here is a working example](https://github.com/tunecino/yii2-app-builder/blob/master/auth/models/User.php) in case you need anyone.

Comment: When I enable the session I can get the user id from `Yii::$app->user->id`, and the `findIdentityByAccessToken` is returning true, also the 'identityCalss' is set.

Comment: The `getId' simply reading the user id from `$identity', and the problem the `$identity' is not been set.

Comment: I think that enabling the session for my case is a must. The user will submit his mobile number from the mobile app, the system will generate and send the user the OTP, once the user submits the right OTP the system will generate and send the access token, and the mobile app will store it in the mobile.

Then, with each request, the mobile app will attach the token. So the user data will not be requested to keep it in an object.

Comment: Enabling session goes agains the stateless nature of RESTful APIs. There should be something else wrong somewhere not invoking `Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)`. You may find it by comparing your implementation against the example code I've linked, it uses no sessions and user identity is properly loaded.

Comment: @SalemOuerdani thanks, this solved the issue.

Comment: Pleasure is mine. Glad it helped.